# Returning error codes from a DLL

Tags: c, dll, error-handling

I have a dll with a c interface, the functions of which will return error codes, I will also provide an additional function that returns the last error. Does this sound sensible? can anyone point me at any examples that i can use as a template please?

Comment: Make every single function you export return an error code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I will also provide an additional function that returns the last error

That would entail having an `errno`-style global variable holding the last error, right? I'd advise against that, as it would make your library hard to use in a multithreaded application, unless you use thread-local storage. Still, if you want to do this, then the standard C library with its `errno` variable/macro would be a good example.

A simpler and, IMHO, better approach is to just return error codes and if necessary provide some functions that operate on your error codes; e.g., you might want to have a `mylib_strerror` to convert them to human-readable string representations. So, the usage would look like

```
int err = mylib_operation_that_might_fail();
if (err != 0) {
    fprintf("%s\n", mylib_strerror(err));
    exit(1);
}
```

A good example of this style is the `getaddrinfo` API specified in [RFC 3493](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3493.txt).

Answer (score 5):

"The last error" is not a very useful or reliable concept in the context of a DLL. What if the DLL is being used by several processes or threads?

Comment: This can also be made thread-safe by using thread-local storage. Still, I agree with you, it's not very elegant.